# How do you create a variable amount of variables?

Tags: java, variables

I am designing a program in java that processes the function of a graph; the user inputs the degree of x and then a loop runs for the user to input the co-efficients (integers) of all the degrees of x. However, I am struggling with storing this information because I cannot change the variable while the loop is running (if the user is inputing a quadratic function, then 3 variables are required but only 2 varibles are required if it is a linear function) and the variable just gets reassigned values. Is there anyway to change the variable (perhaps if the variable is a, increase the unicode to b the next time the loop runs) or any other method/function that would be useful?

Comment: create a list, and fill that with the amount of elements you need

Comment: You can store the data in list rather that creating different variable, if you are not sure about the degree

Comment: Just keep these values in `array` and store the index somewhere to navigate through it. You can even use dynamic allocation for arrays or some collection instead

Comment: Please add an example of what you're trying to design, maybe for the two cases you're describing. Would make it easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can have a `List<Integer> coefficients = new LinkedList<>()` and add all those int to it.

`LinkedList` is used so that order to which items are added is preserved.

Comment: `ArrayList` should probably be prefered